# In other metric spaces, are "line segments" "different"?

Tags: metric-spaces

I am in the beginning of a topology course. We've seen a bit of metric spaces and we've seen that depending on the metric function, the circles change:

> [image]

I am a bit curious about the following: Do line segments change too? In "common geometry", a "line segment" is the smallest distance between two points. Perhaps when we transport that into other metric spaces with other metric functions, "line segments" get different?

Comment: Usually, a line segment is a set, not a number.

Comment: No, line segments do not change. By the triangle inequality of a metric space, the straight line between two points is the shortest distance between the points.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics#Strong_equivalence

Answer (score 2):

Just as with "circle," there is a notion of "line segment" which makes sense in any metric space:

> In a metric space $\mathcal{M}=(M,d)$, given points $a,b\in M$ the **line segment between $a$ and $b$ in $\mathcal{M}$**, denoted "$\overline{ab}_\mathcal{M}$," is the set of "intermediate" points $$\{c\in M: d(a,c)+d(c,b)=d(a,b)\}.$$

Basically, $\overline{ab}_\mathcal{M}$ consists of those points which are "efficiently on the way" from $a$ to $b$ in the sense of $\mathcal{M}$.

**However, this notion behaves rather weirdly in general!**

Most obviously, a line segment may be (almost) empty. For example, consider a *silly (= *discrete*) metric space* $\mathcal{D}=(D,s)$ where we set $s(x,y)=1$ whenever $x\not=y$. If $a,b$ are distinct points then $\overline{ab}_\mathcal{D}=\{a,b\}$ - there are no "points in the middle" at all.

We can also have "line segments" look very different from lines, even when up to *topology* our metric space is very nice. Consider the **taxicab metric space** $\mathcal{T}=(\mathbb{R}^2,t)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. The topologies $\tau_t$ and $\tau_{euc}$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ induced by $t$ and by the usual (Euclidean) metric respectively are homeomorphic, but for example we have $$\overline{(0,0)(1,1)}_\mathcal{T}=[0,1]^2$$ (this is a good exercise).

In fact, the above notion of line segment **turns out to be pretty poorly behaved in general**, and to my understanding doesn't wind up playing much of a role in the general study of metric spaces. Instead, the more complicated notion of a **geodesic** turns out to be important.